# Apollo Cache is completely empty as are my queries and mutations

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I am using Apollo dev tools, and my queries are empty, on pages that are rendering queries, and my mutations are empty when I run a mutation. I can use the graphql tab just fine. And the cache is completely empty. I dont understand.

I wonder if the cache is never being saved, or if there is something wrong with dev tools. I've had dev tools be buggy before, but this seems quite weird, does apollo not save things to cache by default

This is my apollo client

```
const createApolloClient = (accessToken) => {
  const link = createHttpLink({
    uri: "https://graphql.us.fauna.com/graphql",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });

  return new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache({}),
    link,
  });
};
```

and this is a profile page

```
const fetcher = (url) => fetch(url).then((r) => r.json());

function useAuth() {
  const { data: user, error, mutate } = useSWR("/api/user", fetcher);

  const loading = user?.token === false || user === undefined;

  return {
    user,
    loading,
    error,
  };
}

export default function Profile() {
  const { user, loading } = useAuth();

  return (
    <Layout>
      <main>
        {loading ? (
          <ImageRotate>
            <img src="/logo-3.png" />
          </ImageRotate>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Data user={user} />
            <CreateDadHat user={user} />
          </>
        )}
      </main>
    </Layout>
  );
}

const CreateDadHat = ({ user }) => {
  const [cloudLinks, setCloudLinks] = useState([]);

  const clickMe = () => {
    const isBrowser = typeof window !== "undefined";

    if (!isBrowser) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(window.cloudinary); //
    let widget = window.cloudinary.createUploadWidget(
      {
        cloudName: `kitson-co`,
        sources: ["local", "url"],
        uploadPreset: `dadHats`,
        maxFiles: 1,
      },
      (error, result) => {
        if (!error && result && result.event === "success") {
          // console.log(result.info.url)
          // setCloudLinks([...cloudLinks, result.info.url])
          setCloudLinks((state) => [...state, result.info.url]);
        }
      }
    );
    widget.open(); //
  };

  const removeImage = (e) => {
    const arrayIndex = e.target.getAttribute("name");
    // console.log(cloudLinks)
    // console.log(cloudLinks[arrayIndex])
    setCloudLinks(cloudLinks.filter((item) => item !== cloudLinks[arrayIndex]));
  };

  const [createDadHat, { data: createDadHatData, loading: saving }] =
    useMutation(CREATE_DAD_HAT);

  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log("user >>>>", user);
    const createDadHatResponse = await createDadHat({
      variables: {
        connect: user.id,
        name: data.name,
        image: cloudLinks[0],
      },
    }).catch(console.error);
  };
  console.log(errors);

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="name" {...register("name", {})} />

        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
      {cloudLinks &&
        cloudLinks.map((img, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="imgPreview" key={i}>
              <button className="close" name={i} onClick={removeImage}>
                X
              </button>
              <img src={img} />
            </div>
          );
        })}

      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={clickMe}
        id="upload_widget"
        className="upload"
      >
        Upload files
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

const Data = ({ user }) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_DAD_HATS_BY_USER_ID, {
    variables: { id: user.id },
  });

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading Data...</h1>;

  if (error) return <h1>{error.message}</h1>;

  return (
    <>
      {data && <DadHats user={user} data={data} />}
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data?.findUserByID?.hats, null, 2)}</pre>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Geez Had to do the following

`connectToDevTools: true,`

```
const createApolloClient = (accessToken) => {
  const link = createHttpLink({
    uri: "https://graphql.us.fauna.com/graphql",
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });

  return new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache({}),
    link,
    connectToDevTools: true,
  });
};
```